# Can I improve my odds in a coin flip?

Tags: probability

Let's say it's a fair coin. Based on the previous tosses, can I improve my odds in knowing what could be next? Let's make a 10 toss model : HEADS - H ; TAILS - T Model : HHTTHTTTTT

Comment: Short answer: No. For a longer answer, perhaps you can describe the strategy you had in mind, so that someone can point out where it fails?

Comment: Based on the fact that a single coin flip has a 1/2 probability of getting tails ( same for heads ) i was thinking on the long run the number of tails should be equal to the number of heads.

Comment: Ah, that's called the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). Note in particular the first two sections, on fair coins.

Comment: See about the rule of succession [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession).

Comment: I preferred to change my answer into a comment (as I don't have the time to address the comments right now.)

Comment: @msm, I know little on that subject, but It seems to me that the rule of succession is a way to produce the best guess only out of the previous observations, being a good example of Bayesian updating. For me, however, knowing that a coin is fair seems assuming that we are given complete information on how the randomness of the coin tossing works. (It is like the coin has already been tested infinitely many times to prove its fairness.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers ! You gave me a lot of help .

Comment: If previous tosses were relevant, you would have to know all tosses of the coin since it was produced !!!

Answer (score 3):

By the normal model of it: No.

The normal model of a fair coin is that the probability is 50% and the tosses are independent (so the outcome of earlier tosses do not affect the subsequent tosses).